# Swapping function and special keys on HP Pavilion DV6?

Tags: keyboard, hp-pavilion, shortcut-keys

On my HP Pavilion laptop I have to press an additional <kbd>fn</kbd> key and the corresponding function key to get a function key, e.g. <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> works as <kbd>f3</kbd>, <kbd>f3</kbd> alone only increases the brightness of the screen.

Is there any way to swap the key behaviour, like described here for [Function keys in Apple Keyboard don't work as expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33514/function-keys-in-apple-keyboard-dont-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a problem, it's an option in your laptop BIOS. There is an option in your BIOS that enables FN everytime you press an F key, for quick access. As soon as you enter your bios it won't be a big trouble until you find the option. Hope it helped.

Comment: Works like promised.