# How do I activate Function Keys without pressing the fn button in the mac keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

everyone!

I had to change keyboards at work and they gave me a mac keyboard that wasn't in use. I configured most of it to the point where I can use it, but I noticed that I need to press the `fn` key to activate the Functions `F1~F19` and I was wondering if there is anyway I could flip that.

So what I want to do is have the Function keys as default, and need to hit `fn` whenever I want the other function of the key, such as `Volume Up` or `Eject Disc`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typing this in terminal:

```
sudo su -c "echo -n 0x02 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"
```

enables F keys without needing FN.

To restore, change `0x02` to `0x01`.

Must be run after each reboot.

To make it permanent, you can add the command `echo -n 0x02 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` to the file `/etc/rc.local` above the line `exit 0`. Or you can use `sysfsutils` (check that it's installed with `sudo apt install sysfsutils`) - edit `/etc/sysfs.conf` to include the line

```
module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode = 0x02
```

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in some depth at the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior), including various ways to do it permanently, systemwide.