# How to disable animations to speed up screen updating in Virtual environment

Tags: 14.04, unity, virtualbox, animations

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in VirtualBox under Windows. The screen updating is very slow, especially the effect where it tries to zoom windows and cross-fade between windows. Alt-TAB is almost impossible to use because it is so slow drawing.

I'd like to minimize computationally expensive animations and graphic effects. I do not see appropriate settings in System Settings under Display. Where should I look?

Comment: See here too: https://www.fosslinux.com/4208/how-to-speed-up-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-18-04.htm

Comment: I just added an Ubuntu 18.04 or later answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1264930/327339. Hopefully will help speed up the system a bit on slow computers running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

## How to disable Ubuntu menu animations to speed up the system in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 and later:

- The below techniques are for Ubuntu 18.04 or later (perhaps 17.10 or later).
- *Tested to work in both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04*.

I used this today on a 12-year-old 2008 MacBook White running Ubuntu 20.04 and see a *significant improvement in speed and responsiveness in the system!* It now runs surprisingly well, despite being a really old and slow computer running the latest Linux Ubuntu operating system! (I think it runs better now with Ubuntu 20.04 with menu animations *disabled* than it did even with Xubuntu 16.04, which is what I had on it before). I have also used this today on a slow laptop from 2015, now running Ubuntu 18.04, and I see a significant improvement in speed and responsiveness there too!

### Option 1 of 2 (my preference): use a 1-line command in the terminal:

If you'd like to do this from the command-line, it's a super-simple one-liner!:

```bash
# to disable animations to speed up the computer
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false

# to re-enable animations
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true
```

### Option 2 of 2: use the dconf Editor GUI:

```bash
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key (use the <kbd>Command</kbd> key on a MacBook running Linux), type in "dconf", and click the icon to open the "dconf Editor" application:

[image]

Once in, navigate to **/org/gnome/desktop/interface/**, scroll down a bit, and disable the "enable-animations" setting, shown here:

[image]

All credit goes to Kiran Kumar, here: https://www.fosslinux.com/4208/how-to-speed-up-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-18-04.htm. Thank you Kiran.

## References:

1. [Reduce interface effects to improve performance on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050729/reduce-interface-effects-to-improve-performance-on-18-04/1236864#1236864)

## Related (but not referenced by this answer)

1. [How to disable animations in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792822/how-to-disable-animations-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2):

Install Unity Tweak and Gnome Tweak tools.

In the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool
```

To execute them, type `tweak` in the Unity search bar.