# Reduce interface effects to improve performance on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, performance

I've got an second hand notebook at work with low specs and installed Ubuntu 18.04. The GPU is very old and every effect makes the whole system lag.
Is ther any way to reduce UI effects to improve performance?

Comment: Try a lighter flavor like [Xubuntu or Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/).

Comment: [Openbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox) could benefit you as a lightweight replacement for your window manager.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found out that there's a Tweaks tool and in the *Appearance* tab is an option where you can turn off animations. Just that made the computer breathe again.

You can install Tweaks using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Comment: This is not a valid solution. What's the purpose of having a high end computer that can run games but cannot render simple UI animations? There should be a solution where people can enable the animations and have no graphic issues at all.

Comment: Its not a high end computer and I'm not using games on. The tweak tool worked just fine.

Comment: Massive improvement on my XPS 13 9380 as well. Thanks! Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` to install it.

Answer (score 17):

A reasonable improvement you can make is disabling animations, and this can be done without a tool, directly from the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

To reverse this, just:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true
```

This can also be toggled from `gnome-tweaks`, referenced in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! Turning off animations on my [MacBook 2008 White](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265768/327339) running Ubuntu 20.04 speeds it up significantly! It's now a very usable system despite being a 12 yr.-old laptop that was abandoned and no longer supported by Apple 8 yrs ago or so.

Comment: I've also linked to your answer in my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/663440/how-to-disable-animations-to-speed-up-screen-updating-in-virtual-environment/1264930#1264930.

Answer (score 2):

Although going manually through the `gnome-tweaks` tools and the `dconf-editor` works, the `gsettings` commands as in the other answers did not work for me, in a programmatic/CLI approach on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.

What did work for setting this up beforehand on VMs in the cloud with XRDP was:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/enable-animations false
```